# SELECT FROM @random_table SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I'm having an issue with the following code:

```
DECLARE @table varchar(50), @value int 
SET @table = 'randomTable'

EXEC('SELECT @value = exercicio FROM '+@table+' WHERE cod = 2')
```

I need to do a couple of operations like that one above in some random tables. I want to select a value and store in a variable previously declared. But when I tried to execute that code, I received the following message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@value".

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @value variable is outside the scope of the dynamic SQL statement.  You'll need to return the value as an output parameter:

```
DECLARE 
      @table nvarchar(251) = N'dbo.randomTable'
    , @SQL nvarchar(MAX) 
    , @value int;
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @value = exercicio FROM '+@table+N' WHERE cod=2';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@value int OUTPUT', @value OUT;
```